# how to clone archived branch of a git repo?

Tags: git, github

how can i clone an archived branch of a git repo ?

i tried 
git clone https://github.com/debianmaster/simpleCart/tree/8516bac84fda7c47e1ae2ff11083e5ef0681359a

but it did not work.

i'm trying clone an archived branch of this reposiroty
https://github.com/debianmaster/simpleCart.git

Comment: What is an "archived branch"?

Comment: I'm trying to clone a branch from history of repo

Comment: You just want a local branch starting at `8516bac`?

Comment: yes, correct i want to clone 8516bac84fda7c47e1ae2ff11083e5ef0681359a

Answer (score 2):

1. First, clone the repository:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/debianmaster/simpleCart.git
   cd simpleCart
   ```
2. Then, either move your local `master` to `8516bac`:

   ```
   git checkout master
   git reset --hard 8516bac
   ```

   or
3. Create and switch to a new branch `foo` at `8516bac`:

   ```
   git checkout -b foo 8516bac
   ```